# CSV File Not Found Error when trying to read file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a csv file and Jupyter keeps throwing errors. I am using the full path and still no luck. Carcass Disposal.csv is the name of the file and it is saved to my desktop. I am new to python and coding but I have been googling how to solve this and still can't seem to get it.

My Code:
df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/taylorvanwhy/Desktop/CarcassDisposal.csv")

### Error Message:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/taylorvanwhy/Desktop/CarcassDisposal.csv")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
609
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
611
612

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
460
461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
463
464     if chunksize or iterator:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
818
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
820
821     def close(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
1048             )
1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
1051
1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
1865
1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
1868         assert self.handles is not None
1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
1363             src,
1364             "r",

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
640                 errors = "replace"
641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
643                 handle,
644                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/taylorvanwhy/Desktop/CarcassDisposal.csv'

Comment: it means, the file is not located at given location.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the path provided, "/Users/taylorvanwhy/Desktop/CarcassDisposal.csv", assuming you are using macos(linux paths are usually "/home/$username$/Desktop/"), the issue is exactly what the error says, path/file does not exist. You mentioned the filename is "Carcass Disposal.csv", while the path provided does not include that space. Next time, try right click -> Get Info -> copy the path from there.